# Hide Title on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseclick-event

I have a button element which shows dropdown when i click on that. It also shows title.

My problem is if i click on button , title of button appears above values of dropdown. I want to hide title when i click on button.

I want something similar to gmails setting button.

i tried something like this But it removes title of button after first click also it shows title on first click which does not solve my problem

```
$(this).click(
  function() {
    $(this).attr('title', title);
  }
);
```

please find js fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/EuLcK/

Comment: Change CSS of dropdown , and adjust its z-index greater than that of button title.

Comment: please share jsfiddle

Comment: What browser version?

Comment: provide the code for generating the drop down which demonstrates the issue...